# styles being applied to all tr angular2

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am trying to apply `background-color` with `[ngClass]` on a table tr. Styles are getting applied but they are changing all tr's background-color. I want it to be specific to only the one that is being clicked.

Here's my code:

**component.html**

```
  <tr *ngFor="let entitydata of extractData" [ngClass]="{'backcolor':selected}" (click)="select(entitydata)">
                  <td>{{entitydata.clientname}}</td>
                  <td>{{entitydata.partner}}</td>
                  <td>{{entitydata.risk}}</td>
                  <td>{{entitydata.evaluationid}}</td>
                  <td>{{entitydata.status}}</td>
                  <td>{{entitydata.approvedondate}}</td>
              </tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class Component{
public selected:boolean=false;
select(entitydata){
        this.selected =  this.selected===true ? false : true;
    }
}
```

**component.css**

```
.backcolor{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your variable `selected` is common variable for your whole component. That's why whenever you click a row it's value set to true and affects to all rows. You can use `ElementRef` for changing current row style using `$event` parameter rather than `selected`.

Comment: But its being applied conditionally as you can see on the select() method.

Comment: True. But it changes in the scope of current component. That's how oops works.

Comment: Instead of a flag telling that one entity is selected, but not allowing to know *which* entity is selected, use a `selectedEntity` property, containing *the* entity that is selected. And use `[class.selected]="entitydata === selectedEntity"`.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't get you exactly.

Comment: Then think again. Take some time. If you ask a component "is there an entity selected?" (which is what the selected flag allows doing), you still can't know *which* of the entities is selected. So you can't style the row of that entity. You need to be able to ask your component "which entity is the selected one?". And thus style only the row displaying that selected entity. This is pure logic. It has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is , I got your point by this you can manage what you exactly want

In your template :

```
<tr *ngFor="let entitydata of extractData" [ngClass]="{'backcolor': selectedEntity === entitydata }" (click)="select(entitydata)">
    <td>{{entitydata.clientname}}</td>
    <td>{{entitydata.partner}}</td>
    <td>{{entitydata.risk}}</td>
    <td>{{entitydata.evaluationid}}</td>
    <td>{{entitydata.status}}</td>
    <td>{{entitydata.approvedondate}}</td>
</tr>
```

In your component :

```
selectedEntity = {};
select(entity)
{
    this.selectedEntity = entity;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes , entitydata?.selected is for optinal , if there is no selected inside entity it will return false , and upon call we are adding selected property to the entityData.

Comment: An will you please mask this answer as accepted also , please ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to toggle the class added. Say I click on one tr first and then I click on another tr; it doesn't remove the style added to first tr whenI click on the second tr. If you get here what I mean.

Comment: So you just want selection for only one ,tr at a time ?

Comment: Need one help , can you please send me whole entitydata as json , so I can help with better code

Comment: `[
    {
        "clientname":"00045623",
        "partner":"123434",
        "risk":"High",
        "evaluationid":"Acceptance",
        "status":"High",
        "approvedondate":"High"
    },
    {
        "clientname":"00045623",
        "partner":"123434",
        "risk":"High",
        "evaluationid":"Acceptance",
        "status":"High",
        "approvedondate":"High"
    }
]`

Comment: Okay , i got another way for you , try this.

Comment: Why use a selectedIndex, instead of a selectedEntity? This makes code more complex and doesn't allow sorting or filtering the array and keep the selection

Comment: yes , we can also do that , but I have not clear idea about your full requirement , so how can I suggest the best solutions. :)

Comment: Here it is. please check.

Comment: select(i) should be select(entitydata). And you can drop the `let i = index` entirely. And you could simply use `[class.backcolor]="selectedEntity === entitydata"` instead of ngClass